# Sliding, docked Terminal window in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, window

In [this video](http://youtu.be/hvQCXDWh7Wg?t=20m52s) the author has an ever present Terminal window which he can hide (sliding to the bottom) and pull up with a hotkey or something. Does anyone know how to achieve this? It could greatly enhance my workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use Better Touch Tool ( http://www.boastr.net/ ) as that allows for all sorts of bindings, both keyboard and touchpad.

There are quite a few apps out there that do this - you should always do a quick google search imo  ;)

Comment: I'm using Better Touch Tool as well but I want exactly the same thing he has (it's frameless for instance). Anyway you could tell me how to do this with BTT. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Its possible they are using an app to keep the other window on top - I'm not aware of any way of getting the default Mac Terminal to lose its control bar at the top of the screen.